# Java TimerService next execution time is in past

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, scheduling

In our application we have some tasks that have to be run on a schedule.
We use `TimerService` to schedule when they should be run and they have been working fine until we scheduled one of them to run on saturdays.

If the day of week value in the schedule configuration contains a `6` then on saturdays the task is run every second due to `timerService.getTimers().iterator().next().getNextTimeout()` returning a date in the past.

For example if the task is scheduled to run on saturday 17th of march at 08:00:01 from monday to saturday then on saturday it is run at 08:00:01 and the `getNextTimeout()` method returns the next execution time as monday 12th of march at 08:00:01 which results in the task being run again and returning the same next execution time again and so on.

Here's a code snippet for a test that I wrote which exhibits the issue

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.*;

@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class TestTimer {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestTimer.class);

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initTimer() {
        TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig();
        tc.setInfo("TimerTest");
        tc.setPersistent(false);

        timerService.createCalendarTimer(
                new ScheduleExpression()
                    .second(1)
                    .minute(0)
                    .hour(8)
                    .dayOfMonth("*")
                    .dayOfWeek("1-6"),tc);
        logger.info("Timer: "+tc.getInfo());
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute() {
        logger.info("Executing "+TestTimer.class);
    }

}
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code I wrote which leads me to believe the error might be a result of a bug or improper configuration of Glassfish server on which the application is deployed.

Comment: This is not clear. Does the test code you posted run correctly or does it recreate the problem with Saturday schedules?

Comment: Are you also saying that if `dayOfWeek` is set to `1-5`, the schedule rolls to the next week the way you expect?

Comment: The test does exhibit the issue of running every second on saturdays. If `dayOfWeek` is set to `1-5` the schedule behaves as expected rolling over to the next week.

Comment: What happens if you make the timer persistent?

Comment: Making the timer persistent didn't change its bahavior - it still runs every second.

Comment: I'd say it's time to go over to the Glassfish github issue tracker and file a bug report :-(  I did a quick search (on Google as well) and didn't find anything.  Make sure to include the extra info from the comments above.

Comment: Can you try a different version of Glassfish?

Comment: Looks like this is an open issue for Glassfish - [issue1](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/20673) and [issue2](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/20851). Looks like it's difficult to reproduce hence no fix is available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue for Glassfish - [issue1](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/20673) and [issue2](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/20851). Looks like it's difficult to reproduce hence no fix is available.

Comment: You should add your information (and much simpler example) to the open issue.